# Do we need both an App and a Component for Lightning Out?

Tags: lightning, lightning-out

All of the examples for Lightning Out, such as [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) shows that we need an app and a component. Is there a way to use just an app or just a component? Ideally, I'd like to just be able to write an App and not need the extra burden of a component as well.

### Documented Example

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lcvfTest", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("ui:button",
          { label : "Press Me!" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Ideally, I'd prefer if I could just create the app itself in createComponent or something, so that I don't need to have a small three-line application bundle just for the sake of bootstraping a component.

Comment: I've tried a few different configurations. What I think is happening is that the `use` function explicitly replaces whatever is in the body of the app with the new content generated in `createComponent`.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Curiously, $Lightning.createComponent does create apps as well as components (which I proved via console logs), but I can't seem to get the app to render. Looks like I might have to deal with using both, but it seems like overkill, since we can't bundle components/apps together. We really need better source code organization. Apex Code has the same problem, but it seems like Lightning could have fixed this... and failed.

Comment: I think we need both. For sure we need app, because the ltng:outApp is need to bring it outside lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the small little Lightning app bundle is needed. Salesforce uses this "dependency app" to bundle all the transitive dependencies of the Lightning components.